# android : stop a sticky service

Tags: android, service, wear-os

I am developping a wear app.
I start a sticky service in the wear when I receive a dedicated event.
This service returns `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`.

My question is : how can I stop definitively this service?

I need it to be restarted if Android stops it because of low memory, but I need to be able to stop it definitively by code.

I tried to stop it using `stopService(Intent i)` or `stopSelf()` but the service gets recreated each time.

Thank you for your help.

jn.

Comment: please post some code where your starting the service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `stopService(intentOfYourService)` at `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` and give the Intent you created at `onCreate()` (or elsewhere) to the parameteres.

Comment: I only did it at onDestroy as I want the service to keep running at onPause.

Comment: But : it was a mistake on my side, using stopself() the service does not restart even if it is sticky. Thanks for helping